# oscola and babel

Tags: biblatex, babel

Using pdfLaTeX 3.1415926-2.5-1.40.14 (TeX Live 2013/Debian) with different versions of biblatex+biber+oscola, including the latest available, I get several errors when I include babel[italian] alongside with oscola.

Here are two mwe's I prepared.

---

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{jobname.bib}
@jurisdiction{VanGendenLoos,
keywords = {eu},
title = {NV Algemene Transport- en Expeditie Onderneming van Gend \& Loos contro Amministrazione olandese delle imposte},
shorttitle = {Van Gend en Loos},
number = {26/62},
indexnum = {1963},
date = {1963-02-05},
journaltitle = {Racc.},
pages = {3},
institution = {ECJ},
}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,indexing=cite,ibidstyle=uc]{biblatex}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footcite}{\multicitedelim}
\addbibresource{jobname.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=cases, title={Indice della giurisprudenza}, intoc]
\makeindex[name=legislation, title={Indice della legislazione}, intoc]
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eucasesnum}{cases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eutreaty}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{euregs}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eudirs}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eudecs}{legislation}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\chapter{Caso}
caso\footcite[punto 3]{VanGendenLoos}.

\backmatter
\printindex[legislation]
\printindex[cases]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[nottype=commentary,
          nottype=jurisdiction,
          nottype=legislation,
          nottype=legal,
          heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

When I include babel, I get *Bibliography string 'eucase' undefined(biblatex) at entry 'VanGendenLoos' on input line 39*. In the output, in the footnote, the first word *Case* becomes **eucase**.

---

Here I tried to use the bibliography file *oscola-examples.bib* provided with the package.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{book}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[italian]{babel}

\usepackage[backend=biber,style=oscola,indexing=cite,ibidstyle=uc]{biblatex}
\DeclareMultiCiteCommand{\footcites}[\mkbibfootnote]{\footcite}{\multicitedelim}
\addbibresource{oscola-examples.bib}
\usepackage[style=british]{csquotes}

\usepackage{imakeidx}
\makeindex[name=cases, title={Indice della giurisprudenza}, intoc]
\makeindex[name=legislation, title={Indice della legislazione}, intoc]
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eucasesnum}{cases}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eutreaty}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{euregs}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eudirs}{legislation}
\DeclareIndexAssociation{eudecs}{legislation}

\listfiles

\begin{document}
\chapter{Caso}
\textcite{antaios85}.

\backmatter
\printindex[legislation]
\printindex[cases]
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[nottype=commentary,
          nottype=jurisdiction,
          nottype=legislation,
          nottype=legal,
          heading=bibintoc]
\end{document}
```

I get the warnings *string 'casenote' undefined* and *string 'firstpublished' undefined*, and this reflects in **casenote** and **firstpublished** appearing in the bibliography.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: The package isn't really suitable for other languages than english. It contains only an english-oscola.lbx. You could load this lbx and then redefine the strings: `\DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{english-oscola}
\DefineBibliographyStrings{italian}
{eucase={.....}, ....}`

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Want to make that an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package isn't really suitable for other languages than english. It contains only an english-oscola.lbx. You could load this lbx and then redefine the strings:

```
 \DeclareLanguageMapping{italian}{english-oscola}       
 \DefineBibliographyStrings{italian} 
     {eucase={.....}, 
      ....
     }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it solved my problem. Would you like to tell me (or to redirect me to the appropriate source) how should I prepare a file italian-oscola.lbx? I made a copy of the original file and tried the obvious change \DeclareRedundantLanguages{italian}{italian} (and then texhash), but it was like I did nothing.